# Interior point of closed curve on triangular lattice with maximum curvature

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology, recreational-mathematics

Suppose you have a triangular lattice, and you are tracing out a polygonal closed curve, show that if the internal angles are more than 60 then there must be a point on the lattice in the interior of the curve.

This problem came up when I was trying to solve this problem:[from James Tanton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8vRR.jpg)
Which could be easily solved by pick’s theorem and in fact a converse of this could be used to prove my question, however I was looking for a simpler approach more similar to a [Pestov-Ionin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pestov%E2%80%93Ionin_theorem) theorem for polygonal curves

Comment: Your question is a tad vague. Are you working in Eucidean geometry? If so then I suppose triangular lattice means [this](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/An-illustration-of-a-triangular-lattice-grid-left-and-a-hexagonal-lattice-grid-right_fig8_241779221)? And if so, why wouldn't a tiny square, whose interior angles are $90^\circ$, and that does not enclose a point on the lattice, give a simple counterexample?